# Regex expression to get all files that are NOT csv? I use .*\.csv$ to get all files ending in .csv, but I want the negative of this

Tags: regex, csv, file

I use .*.csv$ to get all files ending in .csv, but I want to get all files that are not ending in .csv.
Of course I could use .*.(tif|xls|pdf|jpg|etc)$ but is there not a way to say all files except .csv?

Tried everything in the regex101 test site but was unsuccessful :(

Comment: Are you using `find` and `grep` to filter?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this.

```
(?!\.csv$)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code rather than posting only code.

Answer (score 1):

You got the gist of it. For negating a string using an **extended regex** you'll have to "list" everything that's permitted in a way that can't match the excluded string; not only it's tricky, but the regex can become very long and inefficient:

```
^.{1,3}$|.*([^.]...|[^c]..|[^s].|[^v])$
```

<sup>**remark:** thanks to the anchor `$`, it ended-up simpler than what I though it would be.</sup>

This ERE selects:

1. Anything that's shorter than `.csv` (for ex. `c.v`)
2. Anything that doesn't have a `.` at the fourth position starting from the end (for ex. `json2csv`)
3. Anything that doesn't have a `c` at the third position starting from the end (for ex. `a.tsv`)
4. Anything that doesn't have a `s` at the second position starting from the end (for ex. `a.ctv`)
5. Anything that doesn't have a `v` as the last character (for ex. `a.csw`)

---

More powerful engines (for ex. `perl`) provide a negative look-behind that you can use for this kind of task:

```
.*(?<!\.csv)$
```

This PCRE means: any string (`.*`), as long as it doesn't end with `.csv` (`(?<!\.csv)$`).

---

If you're using `grep` or `sed`, it's easier to use the positive regex:

```bash
grep -v '\.csv$'

sed '/\.csv$/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

see: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Rqd732/1)

```
(?(?=^[^.]*.csv$)|(^[^.]*.*$))
```

- Conditional (?(?=^[^.]*.csv$)|(^[^.]*.*$))
- Conditionally matches one of two options depending on whether the lookaround matches
- Positive Lookahead (?=^[^.]*.csv$)
  Assert that the Regex below matches
- ^ asserts position at start of a line
- Match a single character not present in the list below [^.]
- matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  . matches the character . with index 4610 (2E16 or 568) literally (case sensitive)
  . matches any character (except for line terminators)
  csv matches the characters csv literally (case sensitive)
  $ asserts position at the end of a line
  If condition is met, match the following regex  — always finds a zero-length match
  Else match the following regex (^[^.]*.*$)
  1st Capturing Group (^[^.]*.*$)
  ^ asserts position at start of a line
  Match a single character not present in the list below [^.]
- matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  . matches the character . with index 4610 (2E16 or 568) literally (case sensitive)
  . matches any character (except for line terminators)
- matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  $ asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can use it to filter out the lines that end with `.csv`. For example `printf '%s\n' a.v json2csv a.ctv a.csw .csv a.csv | grep -P '(?(?=^[^.]*.csv$)|(^[^.]*.*$))'` highlight the correct lines but still shows the `\.csv$` ones; My guess is that the regex allows 0-length matches

Comment: When you want to delete the lines containing a `.csv` file, you should do a replace using the regular expression: `^[^.]*.csv$` (or something like that, because this one leave empty lines in the list.)